# How to create a dict-type class attribute with Numba?

Tags: python, numba

I'd like to use a dictionary in a Numba class, but I am not sure what to put for the type spec:

```
@numba.jitclass([("cnts", ???)])
class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cnts = numba.typed.Dict.empty(
            key_type=numba.float64, value_type=numba.int64
        )
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me on Numba 0.45.1:

```
import numba

@numba.jitclass([("cnts", numba.types.DictType(numba.float64, numba.int64))])
class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cnts = numba.typed.Dict.empty(
            key_type=numba.float64, value_type=numba.int64
        )

    def add(self, x):
        if x not in self.cnts:
            self.cnts[x] = 0
        self.cnts[x] += 1

c = Counter()
c.add(1.1)
c.add(1.1)
c.add(0.5)
print(c.cnts)  # {1.1: 2, 0.5: 1}
```